# Run a re-authentication as a background task if external service returns "Unauthorised"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-6.0

I want to authenticate against an external service in the background. So, whenever a user calls an API to fetch data exposed through my service and the external authentication service returns unauthorised, I want to in the background re-authenticate the user and return the data they were trying to fetch. What would be the best way to solve this? Is using a middleware feasible?

```
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

public NotificationService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory,
    IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
{
    _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
}
public async Task FetchNotifications(string projectId)
{
    try
    {
        string notificationURL = _appSettings.BaseURL + "notifications";
        HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(
            HttpMethod.Get,
            notificationURL)
        {
            Headers =
            {
                { HeaderNames.Authorization, "Bearer " + _appSettings.bearerToken }
            }
        };

        HttpClient? httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
        //If httpResponseMessage returns 401, re-authenticate in the background and re-run
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

This is the task I want to run whenever the external service returns 401

```
private async Task Authenticate()
{
    try
    {
        HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(
            HttpMethod.Post,
            _authenticationSettings.AuthenticateURL)
        {
            Headers =
            {
                { HeaderNames.Authorization, _authenticationSettings.Token }
            }
        };

        HttpClient? httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

        if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            await using Stream contentStream =
                await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        
            AuthToken? token = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
                <AuthToken>(contentStream);
            //To-Do: store token in session (?)
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "as a background task"? If you need access to the external API to return a response to your client, your client will have to wait for re-authentication to complete.

Comment: @JonasHøgh What I mean is that my service will be making calls to that external service to fetch data and if the token generated has expired, I want to be able to globally catch the 401 returned and re-authenticate in the background rather than making a check on each request I would make to the external service.

Comment: Your current middleware approach looks like it will perform auth on every request - is that what you want? I would probably go for a higher order function to wrap all your API calls and use something like Polly to retry when the API responds 401. See e.g. https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2017/05/re-authorization-and-onretry-with-polly/

Answer (score 0):

**Using middleware is feasible.**

Usually in our certification process, we log in to get the `code`, and then use the `code` to get the `token`. `Token` has an expiration date, when invalidated, use the `old token` to get the `refreshed token`.

---

In your scenario, it is possible to determine in the middleware whether the current token is within the validity period. Then effectively next directly to the next middleware, invalid to get the refreshed token, and then next to the next middleware.